# Find the sibling td element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that looks like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class='class1' id='id1'></td>
    <td class='class2' id='id2'></td>
    <td class='class3' id='id3'></td>
    <td class='class4' id='id4'><button id='editButton'></button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='class1' id='id1'></td>
    <td class='class2' id='id2'></td>
    <td class='class3' id='id3'></td>
    <td class='class4' id='id4'><button id='editButton'></button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The code below shows me `id4`:

```
$("#editButton").on("click", function(){
   alert($(this).parent().attr("id"));
});
```

Now I need to reach `id3` which is the closest one. The functions `.next('class3')` and `.closest('class3')` do not help me or i am using them in a wrong way. Please help me

Comment: So what is `#editButton`??? I devine it from your posted result but...

Comment: `#editButton` is a button inside of class4

Comment: So just `$(this).closest('td').prev().attr("id")`  but FYI, this is invalid HTML markup regarding duplicated IDs...  Clicking on second `#editButton` won't fire any event here

Comment: @A.Wolff Oh this helps me a lot. Thank you!

Comment: @A.Wolff +1 to use .prev()  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1st :** id must be unique

so your code should like

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class='class1' id='id1'></td>
    <td class='class2' id='id2'></td>
    <td class='class3' id='id3'></td>
    <td class='class4' id='id4'><button class="editButton"></button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='class1' id='id5'></td>
    <td class='class2' id='id6'></td>
    <td class='class3' id='id7'></td>
    <td class='class4' id='id8'><button class="editButton"></button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and in js

```
$(".editButton").on("click", function(){
   alert($(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(3)').attr("id"));
});
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. Why do this have to be so complicated ehh

Comment: @divHelper11  its not complicated  just .closest() to go to parent tr and find the third td  thats it